# How does (My)SQL evaluate chained LEFT/INNER JOINs?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

We have 3 Tables given:

```
T1:               T2:              T3:

id | t3_id        id | name        id | t2_id
----------        ---------        ----------
1  | 2            1  | abc         1  | 1
2  | NULL         2  | 123         2  | 1
3  | 1            3  | ab1         3  | 3
4  | 4            4  | 32b         4  | 2
```

Now we had the following JOINs tested:

### 1.:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.t3_id = T3.id
INNER JOIN T2 ON T3.t2_id = T2.id
WHERE T2.name = '%'
```

This case is clear. Results:

```
T1.id | T1.t3_id | T3.id | T3.t2_id | T2.id | T2.name
-----------------------------------------------------
1     | 2        | 2     | 1        | 1     | abc
3     | 1        | 1     | 1        | 1     | abc
4     | 4        | 4     | 2        | 2     | 123
```

### 2.:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.t3_id = T3.id
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T3.t2_id = T2.id
WHERE T2.name = '%'
```

This one is also clear:

```
T1.id | T1.t3_id | T3.id | T3.t2_id | T2.id | T2.name
-----------------------------------------------------
1     | 2        | 2     | 1        | 1     | abc
2     | NULL     | NULL  | NULL     | NULL  | NULL
3     | 1        | 1     | 1        | 1     | abc
4     | 4        | 4     | 2        | 2     | 123
```

### 3.:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.t3_id = T3.id
INNER JOIN T2 ON T3.t2_id = T2.id
WHERE T2.name = '%'
```

This one is a bit strange. Result (same as the first one):

```
T1.id | T1.t3_id | T3.id | T3.t2_id | T2.id | T2.name
-----------------------------------------------------
1     | 2        | 2     | 1        | 1     | abc
3     | 1        | 1     | 1        | 1     | abc
4     | 4        | 4     | 2        | 2     | 123
```

I don't understand how MySQL evaluates this expression. Why it does ignore the LEFT JOIN and seems to prefer the INNER JOIN.

If **I** read this query it's like:

1. Take data from T1
2. Take data from T2 via LEFT JOIN (means: only if possible, else take NULL data)
3. Take data from T3 via INNER JOIN (means: remove all T2 data that cannot be joined via this INNER JOIN)

But it seem's like I have to read the query backwards?!

Could someone please explain this scenario to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left join is something like "OR" and INNER JOIN something like "AND". So there is precdence like this

```
t1 left join (t2 inner join t3)
```

This is significiant different with

```
(t1 left join t2) inner join t2
```

Answer (score 6):

`INNER JOIN` is applied to the result you already have (ie `T1 LEFT JOIN T3`), not only to `T3`.

You read it like :

```
(T1 LEFT JOIN (T3 INNER JOIN T2))
```

But it's like :

```
((T1 LEFT JOIN T3) INNER JOIN T2)
```